# where I can get video encoding cookbook/ PDF/ tutorial

Tags: video, transcoding, transcode

I need some reference (cookbook, PDF, tutorial or anything) for all about transcoding video things.

it will pleasure if anyone here can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here are some good video encoding libraries and pdfs.**

[[Book1-PDF]](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/AV0506/s0561282.pdf)
[[Book2-PDF]](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee290t/sp04/lectures/video_coding.pdf)
[[Book3-PDF]](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CD8QFjAC&url=http://evalsvc.googlecode.com/files/Introduction%2520to%2520Video%2520Coding.pdf&ei=GFB6Ub2BKMHTrQfKt4DQDA&usg=AFQjCNF0_IK9t4rqmeXba9gIEcPeqa_5yg&sig2=-QaDflA6KoETMD4WdKAgxA&bvm=bv.45645796,d.bmk)

Comment: Hi Shangkar sorry just see your reply, thank you so much for your share, GBU